# Bitmap size > 0, but recognized text block size = 0

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, camera-view

Android Studio 3.6

I try to recgnized text on check (paper).
I use this lib **CameraView** for get picture and use **Firebase ML Kit** to recognize image.

here image:
[image]

```
implementation "com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.6.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
```

in my xml layout:

```
<com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
            android:id="@+id/cameraView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            app:cameraAudio="off"
            app:cameraMode="picture"
            app:cameraPictureFormat="jpeg"
            app:cameraRequestPermissions="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileDetailsToolbar" />
```

So in my Activity:

```
private fun initLogic() {
       dataBinding.cameraView.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        dataBinding.cameraView.addFrameProcessor(object : FrameProcessor {
            override fun process(frame: Frame) {
                Debug.d(TAG, "addFrameProcessor: process: frame = $frame")
                var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
                if (frame.dataClass == ByteArray::class.java) {
                    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    val yuvImage = YuvImage(
                        frame.getData(),
                        ImageFormat.NV21,
                        frame.getSize().getWidth(),
                        frame.getSize().getHeight(),
                        null
                    )
                    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(
                        Rect(0, 0, frame.getSize().getWidth(), frame.getSize().getHeight()),
                        90,
                        out
                    )
                    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
                    Debug.d(
                        TAG,
                        "addFrameProcessor: process_dataClass: ByteArray, imageBytes_size = " + imageBytes.size
                    )
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
                } else if (frame.dataClass == Image::class.java) {
                    Debug.d(TAG, "addFrameProcessor: process_dataClass: Image")
                    val image: Image = frame.getData()
                    bitmap = AndroidUtil.image2Bitmap(image)
                }
                Debug.d(TAG, "addFrameProcessor: process: bitmap_result = $bitmap")
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    runDetector(bitmap)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun runDetector(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "runDetector: bitmap = $bitmap")
        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)
        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceTextRecognizer
        detector.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseVisionText ->
                Debug.d(TAG, "runDetector: processImage: firebaseVisionText = $firebaseVisionText")
                processTextResult(firebaseVisionText)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Debug.e(TAG, "runDetector: processImage: e = $e")
            }
    }

    private fun processTextResult(firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText) {
        Debug.d(
            TAG,
            "processTextResult: textBlocks_size = " + firebaseVisionText.textBlocks.size
        )
        var detectedText = "\n"
        firebaseVisionText.textBlocks.forEach {
            detectedText += it.text + "\n"
        }
        Debug.d(TAG, "processTextResult: detectedText_start\n")
        Debug.d(TAG, detectedText)
        Debug.d(TAG, "processTextResult: detectedText_end")
}
```

And here logcat:

```
activity.ScanCheckActivity: addFrameProcessor: process_dataClass: ByteArray, imageBytes_size = 137056

activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): runDetector: processImage: firebaseVisionText = com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText@e34f1b5
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: textBlocks_size = 0
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: detectedText_start
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): 
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: detectedText_end


ScanCheckActivity( 8140): addFrameProcessor: process_dataClass: ByteArray, imageBytes_size = 211184
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: textBlocks_size = 0
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: detectedText_start
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): 
activity.ScanCheckActivity( 8140): processTextResult: detectedText_end
```

As you can see the **imageBytes_size > 0** but **textBlocks_size = 0**

Comment: `try to recgnized text on check from coffee` ??? What are you trying to tell us?

Comment: @blackapps it's invoice (check) paper. I take picture from it and try to recognize it

Comment: Are you displaying the bitmap in an ImageView to check if it is ok? Nobody can help you as this is not reproducable code. You produce a jpg. Save it to file. Put it somewhere on the internet so anybody interested can download the file. Then post only code to ocr the file once it is on an Android device.

Comment: @blackapps I was updated my post. Added image

Comment: Ok. Hope someone tries it out. I do not use that lib, sorry.